# Rsync with .dd.xz files

Tags: linux, rsync, dd, xz

I am trying different ways to update/write an image on a linux device and using rsync for this.

For file system synchronization rsync checks and only transfers missing /changed files reducing the bandwidth.

In similar way I created a binary file of 10MB(original.bin) and modified this file by adding few changes (modified.bin)and tried to rsync the original.bin file.First time it transfers the whole file as there is no copy on the device.Next modified.bin file is renamed to original.bin and did rsync. It only transferred changes in the modified.bin I want to know if this is the same with .dd.xz files as well. I have 2 .dd.xz files (image1.dd.xz and image2.dd.xz which has few dlls and mono packgaes added) and when these files are extracted to .dd files and rsync transfers only changes.

But when i rsync the files as .dd.xz it transfers the whole file again. Can some one help me to understand if this is expected behaviour or rsync behaves same on .dd files as with any other text files?